# Stackpanel add item animation

Tags: wpf, scroll, slide, stackpanel, itemscollection

I've been struggling a while with marquee-style image scrolling control.

At a moment, I stuck up with templated ItemsControl:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="itemsTemplate">
        <Image Source="{Binding AbsolutePath}"></Image>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemsTemplate}" x:Name="ic"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow, Path=DataItems}" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                                    VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" >                    
            </VirtualizingStackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

ItemsControl is bound to ObservableCollection, so I can add items at runtime. As soon as item goes off-screen it's removed from ObservableCollection.

The last thing to do is implementing custom item add behavior (smooth slide-in instead of insert-translateothers behavior).
Shall I derive from StackPanel to achieve such effect or just perform DoubleAnimation on currently adding item?
Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: [Animate WPF Datatemplate when item added to Listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637844/animate-wpf-datatemplate-when-item-added-to-listbox/638924#638924). Will it suit your needs?

Comment: Thanks, it's I've been looking for.