# Animate WP7 datatemplate element when first added to listbox

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-mobile, listbox, datatemplate

Hey all, I'm trying to apply an animation to any element that gets added to a datatemplate in WP7's subset of silverlight. I'm having some issues though. While it appears to be quite possible in WPF ( [Animate WPF Datatemplate when item added to Listbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637844/animate-wpf-datatemplate-when-item-added-to-listbox) ) using DataTemplate.Triggers, WP7's silverlight doesn't have the Triggers property for DataTemplates. As such, how would I go about doing this on the winphone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you have a `DataTemplate` that is used as the `ListBox.ItemTemplate` property value in XAML? If this is the case, you should be able to handle the `Loaded` event on the root element of the `DataTemplate` in code behind. This event will be invoked as each `DataTemplate` 'instance' is created, alowing you to fire a `Storyboard`.

Comment: I found a hackity work around, but I'll definitely keep this in mind for future use. Thanks amigo.

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight 4 added the concept of **LayoutStates** to the ListBoxItem control, this allowed you add animations for state transitions including things like BeforeLoaded to AfterLoaded. Sadly this functionality isn't baked into WP7 (based on Silverlight 3).

There are some workarounds till that changes with the "Mango" release, including the solution ColinE mentions.

Some resources are: [Animate your #WP7 ListBoxItems while being un-/loaded](http://brainafk.com/animate-your-wp7-listboxitems-while-un-loaded) and [Reactive Extensions #3: Windows Phone 7](http://tozon.info/blog/post/2010/10/13/Reactive-Extensions-3-Windows-Phone-7.aspx)

Comment: Cool - LayoutStates is new to me :-)