# Horizontally centered horizontal ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout

How can I create horizontally oriented `ItemsControl`, where items are aligned the same way how these two labels are aligned in this `Grid`?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Column="1">Text 1</Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="3">Text 2</Label>
</Grid>
```

I already have a View for the items, so using `ItemsTemplate` is probably not an option.

## Resources

Here are some tutorials and articles about creating your own custom panel. Hope this will help someone with similar problem...

[UniformGrid for Silverlight](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2009/01/uniform-grid/)
[Animate WPF Datatemplate when item added to Listbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637844/animate-wpf-datatemplate-when-item-added-to-listbox)
[Creating Custom Panels In WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37348/Creating-Custom-Panels-In-WPF.aspx)
[FishEyePanel/FanPanel - Examples of custom layout panels in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/wpf/panels.aspx)
[WPF - A Constraining Stack Panel](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/const_panel.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the closest you could get without writing your own panel would be:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TheItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Control.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Note that I'm .NET-less at the moment so cannot test the above.

Comment: This won't give me what I need. :-( It's like if in the central `ColumnDefinition` would have been `Width="2*"`. Is it somehow possible to create a Panel by using `Grid` internally, instead of actually calculating the positions of individual elements? I've looked into an implementation of `StackPanel` and it seems VERY complex, so any nice workaround would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are right that one of the solutions is writing my own panel, which is what I have finally decided to do, so I will mark your answer as accepted. Pity I wasn't able to find an easier solution, building custom panel is quite complex.